# Creating a Quiz but the Java wont check the answers

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a test but for some reason the code i have to check the answers and return the numeric grade and letter grade wont return anything. I have tried to fix this issue for a few hours but i have have no idea what the problem is. Is the button not connecting to the function or is the function not able to calculate the answer due to some error in the format.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>CIS44 Quiz</h1>
<form name="questions">
<p>
Question #1: You can test a condition with an if...else statement or with a if...elseif...else statement.
</p>
<input type="radio" name="ques11">True<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques12">False<br />
<p>
Question #2: XHTML stands for Extensible Hypertext Markup Language
statement.
</p>
<input type="radio" name="ques21">True<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques22">False<br />
<p>
Question #3: A web page can contain the following:
</p>
<input type="checkbox" name = "H1">A.) HTML<br />
<input type="checkbox" name = "H2">B.) XHTML<br />
<input type="checkbox" name = "H3">C.) CSS<br />
<input type="checkbox" name = "H4">D.) JavaScript<br />
<p>
Question #4: Which of the following is used to include JavaScript in HTML or XHTML?
</p>
<input type="radio" name="ques41">script="text:javascript"<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques42">script style="text/javascript"<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques43">script type="text/javascript"<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques44">script type="JS"<br />
<p>
Question #5: Which course inclodes PHP and databases with MySQL?
</p>
<input type="radio" name="ques51">CIS120<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques52">CIS122<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques53">CIS159<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques54">CIS156<br />
</form>
<b>
<input type="button" name="toClick" value="Calculate Your Grade" onclick="numericGrade.value=calcAverage(questions)"> 

<input type="button" onclick="calGrade(yourAvg)" value="Show Letter Grade">
</p><i>Your numerical grade on the quiz is:</i> <input type="text" name="numericGrade">

<i>Your letter grade on the quiz is:</i></b> <input type="text" name="letterGrade"></b>
<script type="text/javascript">
var yourAvg=0;
var yourGrade="";

function calcAverage(questions){
    yourAvg=0;
    if (questions.ques11[0].checked == true){
        yourAvg=yourAvg +20;
    }
    if (questions.ques21[0].checked == true){
        yourAvg=yourAvg +20;
    }
    if (questions.H1.checked == true && questions.H2.checked && questions.H3.checked && questions.H4.checked){
        yourAvg=yourAvg +20;
    }
    if (questions.ques43[0].checked == true){
        yourAvg=yourAvg +20;
    }
    if (questions.ques53[0].checked == true){
        yourAvg=yourAvg +20;
    }
    return (yourAvg)
}
function calGrade(yourAvg){
if (yourAvg>=90){
        yourGrade="A";
        questions.letterGrade.value=yourGrade;
    }
    else if (yourAvg>=80){
        yourGrade="B";
        questions.letterGrade.value=yourGrade;
    }
    else if (yourAvg>=70){
        yourGrade="C";
        questions.letterGrade.value=yourGrade;
    }
    else if (yourAvg>=65){
        yourGrade="D";
        questions.letterGrade.value=yourGrade;
    }
    else if (yourAvg<65){
        yourGrade="F";
        questions.letterGrade.value=yourGrade;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form and javascript has errors in them. I cleaned it up. Mostly you need to bind your "questions" variable to your forms so it can use the input variables.

You should add group to your radio button so people can't select True/False at the same time. Happy Coding.

```js
    yourAvg=0; // Global Variable
    yourGrade=""; // Global Variable
    questions = {}; // Global Variable.
    // Binding Form to Questions Global Variable
    var form = document.getElementsByName('questions')[0];
    for(var i=0,len=form.length;i<len;i++) {
        questions[form[i].name] = form[i];
    }

    function calcAverage(form){
        yourAvg=0;
        if (questions.ques11.checked == true){
            yourAvg=yourAvg +20;
        }
        if (questions.ques21.checked == true){
            yourAvg=yourAvg +20;
        }
        if (questions.H1.checked == true && questions.H2.checked && questions.H3.checked && questions.H4.checked){
            yourAvg=yourAvg +20;
        }
        if (questions.ques43.checked == true){
            yourAvg=yourAvg +20;
        }
        if (questions.ques53.checked == true){
            yourAvg=yourAvg +20;
        }
        return (yourAvg);
    }

    function calGrade(yourAvg){
        if (yourAvg>=90){
            yourGrade="A";
            questions.letterGrade.value=yourGrade;
        }
        else if (yourAvg>=80){
            yourGrade="B";
            questions.letterGrade.value=yourGrade;
        }
        else if (yourAvg>=70){
            yourGrade="C";
            questions.letterGrade.value=yourGrade;
        }
        else if (yourAvg>=65){
            yourGrade="D";
            questions.letterGrade.value=yourGrade;
        }
        else if (yourAvg<65){
            yourGrade="F";
            questions.letterGrade.value=yourGrade;
        }
    }
```

```html
<h1>CIS44 Quiz</h1>
<form name="questions">
    <p>
        Question #1: You can test a condition with an if...else statement or with a if...elseif...else statement.
    </p>
    <input type="radio" name="ques11">True<br />
    <input type="radio" name="ques12">False<br />
    <p>
        Question #2: XHTML stands for Extensible Hypertext Markup Language
        statement.
    </p>
    <input type="radio" name="ques21">True<br />
    <input type="radio" name="ques22">False<br />
    <p>
        Question #3: A web page can contain the following:
    </p>
    <input type="checkbox" name = "H1">A.) HTML<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name = "H2">B.) XHTML<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name = "H3">C.) CSS<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name = "H4">D.) JavaScript<br />
    <p>
        Question #4: Which of the following is used to include JavaScript in HTML or XHTML?
    </p>
    <input type="radio" name="ques41">script="text:javascript"<br />
    <input type="radio" name="ques42">script style="text/javascript"<br />
    <input type="radio" name="ques43">script type="text/javascript"<br />
    <input type="radio" name="ques44">script type="JS"<br />
    <p>
        Question #5: Which course inclodes PHP and databases with MySQL?
    </p>
    <input type="radio" name="ques51">CIS120<br />
    <input type="radio" name="ques52">CIS122<br />
    <input type="radio" name="ques53">CIS159<br />
    <input type="radio" name="ques54">CIS156<br />
    <input type="button" name="toClick" value="Calculate Your Grade"
           onclick="questions.numericGrade.value = calcAverage(questions)">

    <input type="button" onclick="calGrade(yourAvg)" value="Show Letter Grade">
    </p><i>Your numerical grade on the quiz is:</i> <input type="text" name="numericGrade">

    <i>Your letter grade on the quiz is:</i></b> <input type="text" name="letterGrade"></b>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample code for some directions.
Some of the problems that you had:
1) Your code didn't have right html to bind to the handler function.
2) Your code was not able to get the controls inside the form.
3) Your code was treating output fields as part of form which they were not.

Hopefully it gives you guidance to proceed further!

```js
var yourAvg = 0;
    var yourGrade = "";
    var letterGrade = document.getElementById('letGrade');
    var numGrade = document.getElementById('numGrade');
    function calcAverage(questions) {
        yourAvg = 0;
        if (questions.elements.ques11.checked == true) {
            yourAvg = yourAvg + 20;
        }
        if (questions.elements.ques21.checked == true) {
            yourAvg = yourAvg + 20;
        }
        if (questions.elements.H1.checked == true && questions.elements.H2.checked && questions.elements.H3.checked && questions.elements.H4.checked) {
            yourAvg = yourAvg + 20;
        }
        if (questions.elements.ques43.checked == true) {
            yourAvg = yourAvg + 20;
        }
        if (questions.elements.ques53.checked == true) {
            yourAvg = yourAvg + 20;
        }
        numGrade.value = yourAvg;
        return (yourAvg);
    }
    function calGrade(yourAvg) {
        if (yourAvg >= 90) {
            yourGrade = "A";
            letterGrade.value = yourGrade;
        }
        else if (yourAvg >= 80) {
            yourGrade = "B";
            letterGrade.value = yourGrade;
        }
        else if (yourAvg >= 70) {
            yourGrade = "C";
            letterGrade.value = yourGrade;
        }
        else if (yourAvg >= 65) {
            yourGrade = "D";
            letterGrade.value = yourGrade;
        }
        else if (yourAvg < 65) {
            yourGrade = "F";
            letterGrade.value = yourGrade;
        }
    }
```

```html
<h1>CIS44 Quiz</h1>
<form name="questions">
<p>
Question #1: You can test a condition with an if...else statement or with a if...elseif...else statement.
</p>
<input type="radio" name="ques11">True<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques12">False<br />
<p>
Question #2: XHTML stands for Extensible Hypertext Markup Language
statement.
</p>
<input type="radio" name="ques21">True<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques22">False<br />
<p>
Question #3: A web page can contain the following:
</p>
<input type="checkbox" name = "H1">A.) HTML<br />
<input type="checkbox" name = "H2">B.) XHTML<br />
<input type="checkbox" name = "H3">C.) CSS<br />
<input type="checkbox" name = "H4">D.) JavaScript<br />
<p>
Question #4: Which of the following is used to include JavaScript in HTML or XHTML?
</p>
<input type="radio" name="ques41">script="text:javascript"<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques42">script style="text/javascript"<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques43">script type="text/javascript"<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques44">script type="JS"<br />
<p>
Question #5: Which course inclodes PHP and databases with MySQL?
</p>
<input type="radio" name="ques51">CIS120<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques52">CIS122<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques53">CIS159<br />
<input type="radio" name="ques54">CIS156<br />
</form>
<b>
<input type="button" name="toClick" value="Calculate Your Grade" onclick="calcAverage(questions)"> 

<input type="button" onclick="calGrade(yourAvg)" value="Show Letter Grade">
</p><i>Your numerical grade on the quiz is:</i> <input type="text" name="numericGrade" id="numGrade">

<i>Your letter grade on the quiz is:</i></b> <input type="text" name="letterGrade" id="letGrade"></b>
```